# iOS shortcuts Open URL with deep link

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I'm building an iOS Shortcut that will craft an Amazon Music URL for a specific song and then open it in the Amazon Music app.  Here's an example URL: `https://music.amazon.com/albums/B002N8TJ18?trackAsin=B002N8TJ36`

If I paste this URL into Safari it works fine, launching the Amazon Music app to the right song.  But using the `Open URL` shortcut, it just launches Amazon Music to the main screen.  Why does this behave differently?  I also found the the `Show Webpage` shortcut shows the correct song on the Amazon Music website.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you add `&do=play` to the end of your link it will start playing the song you have selected.  Just to make sure, you wanted it to play `Wild Child`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I answered my own question.  I have to replace the URL prefix with `amznmp3://albums/B002N8TJ18?trackAsin=B002N8TJ36`.  I found this URL scheme by inspecting the IPA.  However, for some reason it doesn't choose the right song, it only takes me to the album.